# How do I specify the correct location for the xml file?

Tags: c#, cross-platform

How do I specify the correct location for the xml file?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
```

I launch the application in xamarin live - Everything is working.

I collect the application and sign it. I install the application on the phone - the application crashes when I go to the page with this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App14
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ListMain : ContentPage
    {


        public ListMain ()
        {

            InitializeComponent ();
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");


        }


    }
}
```

Here's an outline of my solution. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy31n.jpg

Data.xml: build action = embedded resource

Thank you all for your help.
I changed my code on your advice to understand whether a file is being created or not.
I did it and got "NO" - The code says that the file is not being created. Any ideas why?

```
  string fullPath = Path.Combine(
             System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources), "Data.xml");
            if (File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "YES", FontSize = 20, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End });
            }
            else
            {
                stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "NO", FontSize = 20, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End });
            }
```

Comment: I guess is a DirectoryNotFoundException, you can try using System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) even if I would recommend using assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Data.xml");

Comment: Can you help me write the following code correctly?I tried so much `string fullPath = Path.Combine(
             System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), Data);
             XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fullPath);` and so `string fullPath = Path.Combine(
             System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources), Data);
             XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fullPath);` Visual Studio, underlines the red `"Date"`

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the file under the `Assets` folder and using:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load (Assets.Open ("Data.xml"));
```

Comment: Thank you. I did it and got "NO". `string fullPath = Path.Combine(
             System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources), "Data.xml");
            if (File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "YES", FontSize = 20, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End });
            }
            else
            {
                stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "NO", FontSize = 20, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End });
            } `